# ASP.Net Core 3.1 Entity Framework Core: Foreign key causes cycles

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

I'm using Entity Framework Core in context of ASP.Net core application and I have 3 tables.
Users, Subjects and Invoices. What I want to achieve is User can create an Invoice and assign one of his contacts (Subject) to it. So far, my database diagram looks like following:

[image: Db diagram]

When I try to call Update-Database (code-first approach) with following models, I'm getting errors saying that Foreign key FK_Invoices_Subjects_SubjectId may cause cycles.

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Subject> Contacts { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Invoice
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(Subject))]
    public Guid SubjectId { get; set; }
    public virtual Subject Subject { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(User))]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Subject
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(User))]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
}
```

I understand the problematics of cycling in databases. However, is there a way of achieving my solution with some elegant way? I don't want to copy all Subject fields to Invoice when I can just assign a key. Maybe I could use Fluent API to define On-Delete behavior? If user is deleted, I wanna delete all his subjects and invoices. If subject is deleted, I wanna delete all invoices assigned to this subject. If invoice is deleted, nothing else should be. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I have decided to remove the direct relation between Users and Invoices tables. If I need to list all of user invoices, I'm going to list them using Subjects table and include them for each subject specifically.